# C:\Users\User\Desktop\gatsby-tutorial\.cache\json\_404_.json: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: gatsby

I have been working with gatsby and it was absolutely fine, everything was working as expected and I took a break and when I came back and ran "gatsby develop", I got this error

"SyntaxError: C:\Users\User\Desktop\gatsby-tutorial.cache\json_404_.json: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0

- JSON.parse"

and I was logged out of my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who ran into the same issue, just run "gatsby clean" in your terminal and it should work. At least, in my case it did work.